# Node.js - ytdl-core stream skip to a given time

Tags: node.js, youtube

I have some code like this:

```
const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1, quality: "highest" };
const stream = ytdl(url, {filter : 'audioonly'});
const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);
```

I was just wondering if there was a method of connection or stream that would seek the video to a given time (Or do I have to edit streamOptions and re-create the stream?)